# form input boxes and labels Alignment way off in IE9

Tags: css, spring, jsp-tags, forms

I'm redesigning the skin and layout of a user info form.  Initially it was done using a table, but I really don't want to use a table for the layout.  My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/eNqrM/  I've tested my code in all browsers, Opera 11.x, FF 12.x, Chrome 18.x, Safari 5.1.x and the form looks great.  My problem is IE9.

Please take a look at the code in IE9 and see if anyone can figure out what I've mis-coded as to why the form elements don't line up and some have a different text treatment.  I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the original table-layout if any one wants to compare.  http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/q3sCb/3/  Both sets of code have java spring form tags, so it was a little difficult for me as well to figure it as I am a FED (front-end dev).  Maybe I've got something mixed up here.  I don't know.

Thanks!!

P.S. If modifying the original table-layout is the better way to do this, I'd appreciate some help on how to begin to code that... I haven't used tables for layout in a while.

IE9:

[image]

Comment: For me the forms look identical in Chrome18 and IE9. :s

Comment: I'm confused, because the code you've got looks nothing like the code you posted that's in tables. Is it supposed to? I'm also confused by the non-HTML stuff. What are browsers supposed to do with a tag called <form:someformcontrol>? Or do these get converted to real HTML later on?

Comment: Unless this is a small detail I'm missing, it looks the same in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: @Richard, I've attached a screen shot of what I am seeing in IE9.  The firstname and StreetAddress labels are correct, but the rest of the form elements are indented to the right.  That's not how the form renders in any of the other browsers.  Are you not seeing this display?

Comment: @j08691 I've attached a screenshot of what I am seeing in IE9.  The labels and input boxes are misaligned

Comment: @stommepoes, quite right ... the code I have written looks nothing like what is in the table because I am redesigning the layout using CSS, not tables, as I said.  The <form:> tags you are seeing are java spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this.  May not be the best way, but I wrapped the `input` elements in the `label` tag and added a rule `float:right` to the `input` tag within it.  Thanks for everyone's feedback

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with a relatively straightforward form that has inputs with a value attribute. Not sure if that's actually an answer, but it may help to know that you are not alone in seeing a misalignment. I'm slightly baffled as to why some people are NOT seeing a misalignment. The fact that float:right gives a fix is useful to me and may have something to do with the mysterious hasLayout property that has long been a 'feature' of IE. Floating, left or right, induces 'hasLayout' but may have other consequences. A common fix for not 'having layout' is to give everything a zoom:1 in CSS - this induces 'having layout' and usually without any visual change, because zooming with a factor of 1 doesn't resize anything.